# Use script for SSH Banner before login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, configuration

I'm aware you can run your own scripts for the MOTD in `/etc/update-motd.d` and/or `/etc/motd`, but that's for displaying *after* a user has logged in.

The SSHD config file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) allows you to set an option `Banner`, where it displays text *before* you successfully login. For example:

```
$ ssh user@host
This is a Banner message, that is displayed before login!

user@host's password:
```

As far as I know, the `Banner` option can only be a text file, I don't think it's possible for it to be a shell script or a `.py` file that is then run and displayed, or am I wrong?

Is there some way I can make the `Banner` option execute a script and display the output before login, like I descirbed above?

**Just to clarify:** Like with the MOTD, this Banner script would be run on the server's end, not the client's.

I was directed to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665477/execute-prelogin-scripts-for-ssh), but:

> This doesn't happen before the password prompt shows up, but auth modules are the first ones run after the password is entered.

So it's not exactly what I'm looking for, I want the output of the script to be displayed *before* the password prompt. The original question is *similar* to what I want, however.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. That would be a security risk, where any non-authenticated visitor could trigger execution of a script on your server. What content you want to be in that banner?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Wouldn't it be executed on the host, same as with the MOTD?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/665477/execute-prelogin-scripts-for-ssh ?

Comment: @Dom It sounds close to what I want, however - > "This doesn't happen before the password prompt shows up, but auth modules are the first ones run after the password is entered - they check whether the user is authenticated, after all". It only displays the output *after* a successful login.

Comment: Yes, the script would be executed on the host, and that is a security issue as I explained above. Can you please elaborate what is the exact content you would like to show in the banner?